# Is the spherical growth function of a finite group always a unimodular sequence?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with symmetric generating set $S$, and let the spherical growth function of $G$ (with respect to those generators) be $a_S(n) = |\{g \in G \mid \ell_S(g) = n \}|$, where $\ell_s(g)$ is word length of $g$ with respect to $S$.

For a typical choice of generators (say, transposistions in $S_n$) one expects the sequence $a_S(n)$ to increase early on and then later decrease. But is it possible for the sequence to exhibit more complicated behavior, such as increasing, then decreasing, then increasing again (that is, for the sequence to not be unimodular)?

It is known that there are infinite finitely generated groups without monotonic growth function, and this seems a natural question to ask in the finite case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just calculated the growth series for $A_5$ with generators $(1,2)(3,4)$ and $(2,3,5)$, and it is
$$1,\,3,\,4,\,6,\,8,\,10,\,8,\,10,\,6,\,3,\,1,$$
so it has a little dip in the middle.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I wonder how man times such a sequence can dip up and down.

Comment: There could easily be examples where for some reason there are more elements of even than of odd length (for example), in which case it could oscillate - I will experiment a bit when I have time.

Comment: I'd be really curious, thanks!